# How to Load Dependencies Relative to Defining Module

Tags: sapui5

I made a library project so I can share a formatter and some custom controls between applications. This works pretty well, it's just adding the library to the *neo-app.json* file. Now I can load my common formatter:

*app/neo-app.json*

```
{
    "path": "/resources/shared/",
    "target": {
        "type": "application",
        "name": "mysharedlibrary",
        "entryPath": "/"
    },
    "description": "My shared library"
}
```

*app/Controller*

```
sap.ui.define([
    "shared/formatters"
], function(formatters) {
//etc
```

Then I wanted to add a shared base controller, which already has the formatters set. So I go into my shared library project and add a controller, then add the formatter:

*mysharedlibrary/SharedController*

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "formatters" /* <----- this is the problem */
], function(Controller, formatter) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("shared.SharedController", {
        formatter: formatter
    });
});
```

And then use it in my app:

*app/Controller.js*

```
// fails. Shared base controller can't load formatter. 
sap.ui.define([
    "shared/SharedController"
], function(Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("my.app.controller.App", {

    });
});
```

This approach doesn't work. The app implementing this controller can **find** the controller, but then loading the formatter into the shared controller seems to fail because it can't be found. I'm not sure how to make the Shared Controller load files *relative to it's own path* instead of relative to the implementing application's path.

What do I put in the `SharedController` file to load the formatters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`sap.ui.define`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui/methods/sap.ui.define) supports declaring dependencies relative to the module's own path.

> As a convenience, the name of a dependency can start with the segment `'./'` which will be replaced by the name of the package that contains the currently defined module (relative name).
>
> It is best practice to [...] use relative names for the dependencies whenever possible.

In the case above, if *SharedController.js* and *formatters.js* are stored in the same folder, the dependency of the controller would look like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "./formatters"
], function(Controller, formatter) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("shared.SharedController", {
    formatter: formatter
  });
});
```

If it's in upper directory, then like this: `"../formatters"`, etc.