# How do I tell UI5 where to find my custom modules?

Tags: sapui5

I have a UI5 application where I load the UI5 framework from a CDN and where I have a custom module in the file folder of my application folder. But my application doesn't find my custom module. UI5 searches for it in the framework source. How can I tell my application where to find my custom modules?

My project structure looks like this:

[image: Project structure]

The code of the `index.html` is the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quickstart</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ui.layout, sap.tnt"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"Quickstart": "./"}'
        data-sap-ui-async="true">
    </script>
    <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
            sap.ui.require([
                "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
                "MyModule"
            ], function (XMLView, MyModule) {
                XMLView.create({viewName: "Quickstart.App"}).then(function (oView) {
                    oView.placeAt("content");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content"></body>
</html>
```

And `MyModule.js` is defined like this:

```js
sap.ui.define([], function () {
    "use strict";

    return {
    };

});
```

And this is the error I get in the browser console:

[image: Browser console errors]

Live Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/0qGeSUEhOvzk6ZKB?preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When requiring own modules, you'll have to prefix the dependency path with one of the registered URL prefixes.

Given [this project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGcip.jpg) and  `data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"Quickstart": "./"}'`, the module can be required like this:

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "Quickstart/MyModule",
]/*...*/);
```

---

PS: When **defining** a module with `sap.ui.define`, the dependency path [can be relative.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48958729/5846045)